# Zend_Config_Xml strange behaviour

Tags: php, xml, arrays, zend-framework, config

I have a strange problem with Zend_Config_Xml.

Here is an example.

With this xml file https://gist.github.com/883465

this code:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('config.xml'); 
var_dump($config->get('elements')->get('element')->toArray());
```

gives:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> 
  array(2) { 
    ["a"]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
    ["e"]=> 
    array(3) { 
      [0]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [1]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [2]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  [1]=> 
  array(2) { 
    ["a"]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
    ["e"]=> 
    array(3) { 
      [0]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [1]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [2]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

with this xml file https://gist.github.com/883469

it gives:

```
array(2) { 
  ["a"]=> 
  array(1) { 
    ["attr"]=> 
    string(2) "at" 
  } 
  ["e"]=> 
  array(3) { 
    [0]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
    [1]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
    [2]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

and I expect:

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> 
  array(2) { 
    ["a"]=> 
    array(1) { 
      ["attr"]=> 
      string(2) "at" 
    } 
    ["e"]=> 
    array(3) { 
      [0]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [1]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
      [2]=> 
      array(1) { 
        ["attr"]=> 
        string(2) "at" 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

This is tricky when you want to iterate over elements

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('config.xml'); 
foreach($config->get('elements')->get('element') as $element);
```

which is fine if there are more then one elements, but if you have only one, 
you'll end up iterating over element children!

Any idea?

EDIT:

I came up with an ugly workaround:

if (0 !== $config->get('elements')->get('element')) {
 // 
}

This helps me to identify if there is more then one elements under elements tag.

Very ugly.

Anithing smarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Zend_Config_Xml explicitly collapses such 1-element collections (there's an `if` statement in the source that does this). Some possible workarounds:

- Overload Zend_Config_Xml and fix the loader code so it doesn't collapse 1-element collections
- Overload Zend_Config_Xml and overload `get()` to include your ugly workaround in a cleaner way.
- Use SimpleXML instead of Zend_Config_Xml